# Buddypress, BBPress - deqeue bp, bbp css and get group member count

Tags: buddypress

I have been customizing buddypress, bbpress in my theme.

I have found 2 issues you need to know.

1. I am using less file and removed original css files.

   ```
   /** Remove original bp css **/
   function dequeue_buddypress() {
   wp_dequeue_style('bp-legacy-css');
   wp_dequeue_style('bbp-default');
   }
   add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'dequeue_buddypress');
   ```

However, I found that it also doesn’t get “cover image in single members, single groups”.
I have added it in a theme. I added all original css code into less file and have been working on customization.

Is there any better way to remove original css and use my own less (css) file without losin cover image?
Is there anything more I lose if I remove the original css files?

I have found that “bp-legacy-css-inline-css” code is not loaded.
It’s including cover image and some.
It’s originally after buddypress.min.css.

```
    <style id="bp-legacy-css-inline-css">
    /* Cover image */
    #buddypress #header-cover-image {
        height: 400px;
        background-image: url(....);
    }

    #buddypress #create-group-form #header-cover-image {
        margin: 1em 0;
        position: relative;
    }

    </style>
```

something like this.
This has been removed as well when I removed original css code.

I also created a folder (/wp-content/themes/my-theme/buddypress/css/buddypress.css).
It doesn’t load the original one and works fine. But it’s not loading “bp-legacy-css-inline-css”.
That’s why cover images are not showing.

Is there any solution or am I missing something?

2. How can I get group member amount only NUMBERS?

   ```
   bp_group_member_count()
   ```

It gets with xx “members”. But I just need numbers of the group. I use it in groups-loop.php

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I am leaving no1 answer I found the solution.
There is a tip to override the original css code.
https://codex.buddypress.org/themes/buddypress-cover-images/#about-buddypress-css-overrides

I hope it helps for next person who has the same issue.

I still have not found no 2 issue. if you have any tips, please let me know.

Thank you,